# Caused by: ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'STUDENTS' does not exist DB on mac

Tags: java, spring, macos, hibernate, javadb

I have been facing a problem since the last 3 weeks. The issue can be seen on a mac. I have instructed Hibernate to create the tables for me, but when executing the application it throws the following Exception:

```
Caused by: ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'STUDENTS' does not exist.
```

I am using Java 6, Spring 3, Hibernate 3 & Java DB. I am using Java DB as a in memory database. Below is the code:

```
package com.transactions.config;

import java.util.Properties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean;
import com.transactions.dao.StudentDAO;
import com.transactions.dao.hibernate.StudentHibernateDAO;
import com.transactions.entities.Student;

@Configuration
public class TransactionConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public DriverManagerDataSource dataSourceBean() {
      DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
      // dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;shutdown=false");
      dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:derby:memory:student;create=true");
      dataSource.setUsername("");
      dataSource.setPassword("");
      return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sfBean() {
      AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sfBean = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      sfBean.setDataSource(dataSourceBean());
      properties.setProperty(new String("hibernate.dialect"), new String("org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"));
      properties.setProperty(new String("hibernate.show_sql"), new String("true"));
      properties.setProperty(new String("hibernate.hmb2ddl.auto"), new String("create"));
      properties.setProperty(new String("hibernate.format_sql"), new String("true"));
      sfBean.setAnnotatedClasses(Student.class);
      sfBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
      return sfBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() {
      HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate();
      hibernateTemplate.setSessionFactory(sfBean().getObject());
      return hibernateTemplate;
  }

  @Bean
  public StudentDAO studentDAO() {
      StudentDAO studentDAO = new StudentHibernateDAO(hibernateTemplate());
      return studentDAO;
  }
  }


package com.transactions.dao.hibernate;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import com.transactions.dao.GenericDAO;

public class GenericHibernateDAO<T> implements GenericDAO<T> {

  private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

  public GenericHibernateDAO(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
      this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
  }

  public List<T> findAll() {
      List<T> t = (List<T>) hibernateTemplate.find("FROM Student");
      return t;
  }

  public T findByName(String name) {
      return null;
  }
}


package com.transactions.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private int studentId;
  @Column
  private String name;

  public Student() {

  }

  public int getStudentId() {
      return studentId;
  }

  public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
      this.studentId = studentId;
  }

  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }
}


<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.transactions</groupId>
<artifactId>transactions</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>transactions</name>

<properties>
  <org.springframework.version>3.2.11.RELEASE</org.springframework.version> <!-- 4.1.0.RELEASE -->
  <org.slf4j.version>1.7.0</org.slf4j.version>
</properties>

<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-complier-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
</dependency>
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency> -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.11.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.9</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Below is my test class:

```
package com.transactions.dao.hibernate;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;
import com.transactions.config.TransactionConfiguration;
import com.transactions.dao.StudentDAO;
import com.transactions.entities.Student;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {TransactionConfiguration.class})
public class GenericHibernateDAOTest {

  @Autowired
  private StudentDAO studentDAO;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {

  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {

  }

  @Test
  public void testFindAll() {
      List<Student> students = studentDAO.findAll();
  }
}
```

I have also used HSQLDB for the in memory database but again a similar Exception was raised. I am sure Hibernate, HSQLDB & Java DB should all work on a mac.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised after some time that there was a spelling mistake in the properties. I added the following:

```
properties.setProperty(new String("hibernate.hmb2ddl.auto"), new String("create"));
```

The value should of been:

```
properties.setProperty(new String("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"), new String("create"));
```

This now works.